# SCSS not able to make image into circular container

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to make an image fit into circular container.
I have code here - http://jsfiddle.net/ujpmya8z/2/

Image is not showing as circular, it is showing as square only.

I think '&' is giving some trouble. Though I need it because I want to keep this image inside the grid cell and want to have some properties of grid applied to cell and its content.

HTML

```
<script type="text/html" id="member-card">
  <button
    class="list-item">
        <div class="list-icon">
        <img aria-hidden="true" data-bind="attr: { src: 'https://picsum.photos/72/72' }" />
      </div>
  </button>
</script>

<h1>Responisve Flexbox</h1>


<div class="container">
  <div data-bind="template: {name: 'member-card'}">
    </div>
      <div class='list-item'>1</div>

  </div>
```

SCSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 176px);
  around*/
}

.list-item {
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 170px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  min-width: 170px;

  & .list-icon {
    position: relative;
    width: 1.75rem;
    max-width: 10%;
    padding: 0;
    align-self: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your img doesn’t seem to fill the list-icon.

Comment: Change the mode from "CSS" to "SCSS" and fix your errors. SCSS is less forgiving than CSS. For example, `around*/` is just broken and the compiler doesn't like that you're using four arguments for `rgb()` when it only takes three.

Comment: oops. first error must have been while copy-paste. And rgb() one, I do not know where I get to see these compiler errors in jsfiddle, but for now, I have removed that line. So I have fixed as you mentioned.

Comment: jsfiddle used to give you an indicator for errors. I'm not sure why it's not doing that now. The error messages are buried in the view's `<style>`. I poked around to find them when I noticed that the styles didn't look like they were being applied.

Comment: Add `.list-icon { overflow: hidden; outline: 1px solid red; }`. `overflow` to crop the image and `outline` to see what's actually going on without messing up anything else.